# Unable to access site after deleting an entry from the database

Tags: database

The entry *views.view.media* from the config table in phpmyadmin was accidentally deleted. When visiting the site it giving the error ***The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later***. I'm unable to login or access any page. What can I do to fix this problem? It's drupal 8.2.4.

Comment: Can you go to your server's error log and check what it says there? Or just get the entry back from a backup.

Comment: I didn't had access to the server log but I was able to fix the issue by updating drupal core.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the views in a similar configuration to your current site, on another install, and then copy that row from the database in that install to your current site.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by updating drupal core.